# unable to install magento extension

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, extensions, installation

I was able to install magento extensions but it is not working from 2-3 days. I am getting following error for all extension install. It seems extension server config issue, I sent out mail to magento support but no reply. Please guide on this

```
community/pagayo_pt002: Failed to connect to connect20.magentocommerce.com port 443: Connection timed out

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 
'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away'
in /home/myhome/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/myhome/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/myhome/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/myhome/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/myhome/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/myhome/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT mgbc_co...', Array)
#5 /home/myhome/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECTmgbc_co...', Array)
#6 /home/myhome/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(828): in /home/myhome/public_html/magento/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 235
```

Comment: Anyone able to install any magento community extensions or is it problem with me only? as "Connection timed out" should be server problem so want to know this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your db server is getting down while installing the extension.

You can manually install the extension via ftp filezilla or any other ftp client.

Download the extension from http://freegento.com/

And transfer the files via ftp client (filezilla)

And clear your Magento cache from backend and logout and login again. That's it.

I hope it will help you, don't forget to mark it as correct if it solves your issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it;s working. Any idea why DB is going down so that I can fix it.

Comment: It could be due to less memory or response time.